# Can you prove or disprove the following list of my conjectures?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, perfect-numbers, goldbachs-conjecture

The following three statements are my own conjectures, not a homework problem.

> $a)$ For $n = 3, 4, 5,..$, every square integer $n^2$ can be expressed as the sum of a prime $p$ and two other primes $q$ and $r$ multiplied together with $q, r < n$.
>
> $b)$: (Similar to $a)$) Every positive integer $n>10$ can be written as a sum of a prime $p$ and two other primes (not necessarily distinct) $q$ and $r$ multiplied together.
>
> $c)\,\mathbf{[proven]}$: The digital root of every perfect number except $6$ is $1$.

Can you prove or disprove them? If this is difficult, are there any implications between $a),b)$ and Goldbach's conjecture?

Comment: The conjecture (c) as written is false. $n=2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$ is a perfect number for 9941, but the sum of the digits of the sum of the digits is 28. Need to iterate until a single digit is reached?

Comment: @ReinerMartin possibly, since $2+8=10$

Comment: The digital root of a number is just the residue modulo $9$, unless the number is divisible by $9$, so to show $c)$, we only have to show that every perfect even number greater than $6$ is of the form $9k+1$

Comment: The formulation of $a)$ is unlucky. Do you mean that every perfect square greatert than $4$ has such a representation ?

Comment: $b)$ is false because $10$ cannot be written in such a way.

Comment: But $b)$ seems to be true for $n\ge 11$, which would imply that $a)$ is true (If you mean that every perfect square greater than $4$ has such a representation). For $11\le n\le 1000$ , $b)$ is true.

Comment: $a)$ needs adjusting slightly. Since $qr\ge4$, and $qr<n$ is required, it doesn't work for $n=3,4$

Comment: @nickgard I have changed the statement in a). I meant both $q$ and $r$ must be less than $n$, not their product.

Comment: @Peter edited to $n>10$. How would you go about proving b)?

Comment: To prove such things is usually extremely difficult, Maybe partial results concerning the Goldbach-conjecture are helpful.

Comment: How is conjecture (d) true when $n=32$ (or for any larger even number up to $98$)?

Comment: @simplyfire, supposedly they are your own discovered conjectures, do you offer the bounty for anyone finding the remaining proof ? or do you have a strategy to partition it ?

Comment: @Idle The bounty is offered to anyone who posts a complete proof to at least one of the above conjectures except c). I do not know how to partition a bounty but I guess upvoting and accepting (25 rep) will do the job.

Comment: @DavidK You are right. I shall delete it. However, I'm interested in why it works for $n<30$.

Comment: You could put (d) back, just change 100 to 30.

Comment: I don't think it should be on the list since it only works for a few integers. I might make a separate post about it though.

Comment: TheSimpliFire and @peter and all for the 2nd conjecture, i'm not saying it's a [lemoine's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemoine%27s_conjecture) but whoever solves it can solve lemoine's conjecture immediately .

Comment: @Idle thanks I did not know about Lemoine's Conjecture.  Part b) of the list is probably a stronger version of it as it takes into account the even integers as well.

Comment: @DavidK I have posted it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2538173/on-the-division-of-integers-of-the-form-nnn-frac-n2-frac-n2-frac-n2-by-pi

Comment: I want to give it an upvote for a clever title :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conjecture (c) as written is false. $n=2^{p−1}(2^p−1)$ is a perfect number for $p=2203,$ but the sum of the digits of the sum of the digits of $n$ is 19.

However, if you keep iterating you arrive at 10 it seems. In other words, the [digital root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root) seem to be 1.

Actually, this is correct (all even perfect numbers other than 6 have digital root 1) and has been proven in http://apfstatic.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/s3fs-public/09-comac_digital_roots_of_perfect_numbers%20(1).pdf.

Comment: Yes, I think this needs to be summed again to give $10$. How would you write the statement?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire In fact it is not difficult to show that every perfect even number greater than $6$ is of the form $9k+1$ and hence if we iterate the sum of digits, we eventually reach the digitial root, which must be $1$.

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Comment: It's worth emphasising that this only shows (c) for even perfect numbers - the linked article says nothing about odd perfect numbers.

Comment: Good point. As a further addendum, note that it is not known if any odd perfect numbers exist, and there are none below $10^{1500}.$

Answer (score 0):

(b) is an open problem.

If it weren't, then we would have resolution of both Lemoine's conjecture$^{[1]}$ and Marnell's prime and semiprime conjecture$^{[2]}$ (for which no exceptions below $1 \times 10^8$ exist).

---

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemoine%27s_conjecture

[2] Geoffrey R. Marnell, "Ten Prime Conjectures", Journal of Recreational Mathematics 33:3 (2004-2005), pp. 193--196.