# primes of the form 2+pq

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes

Is it always possible to demonstrate the existence of at least one prime number of the form 2 + pq, where p is an arbitrarily large prime number and q is a prime number greater than p?

Other word, if I pick a prime number p, must there exist at least one prime number of a form 2+pq,
while q is bigger prime number than p?
I know there exist infinitely many of the form 2+np where n is integer (according to Dirichlet theorem) but I wonder if the stated sentence is true too

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3546252/is-this-elementary-number-theoretic-conjecture-already-mentioned-somewhere-or-it?noredirect=1), where not all primes can be odd, so we may take $s=2$.

Comment: This is open , but follows from the Schinzel hypothesis

Comment: The Schinzel hypothesis even implies that for every odd prime $p$ , there are infinite many primes $q>p$ such that $2+pq$ is prime.